# SED: delete lines containing first pattern and not containing second pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file content like that:

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a2 b21
a2 b22
a3 b3
a4 b4
```

I need delete with sed lines which contain a2 and not contain b2. I.e. to get the following result:

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
a4 b4
```

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? It's easier with `awk`.

Comment: Yes. It has to be `sed`.

Comment: your result is containting an a2 b2 that normally does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\ba2\b/!b;/\bb2\b/!d' file
```

or:

```
sed '/\<a2\>/!b;/\<b2\>/!d' file
```

Comment: @OlegG are you using GNU sed? If not try `sed -e '/\<a2\>/!b' -e '/\<b2\>/!d' file`

Comment: But I used without that /</>. It was enough just `sed -e "/a2/!b" -e "/b2/!d" file`

Comment: @OlegG I don't think you will get the correct values if you remove the start/end word boundary anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do:

```
cat file
a1 b1
a2 b2
a2 b21
a2 b22
a3 b3
a4 b4
a2 c3
```

```
awk '$1=="a2" && $2!="b2" {next} 8'
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
a4 b4
```

If field #1 is `a2` and filed #2 is not `b2` skip the line.

Comment: sed miss if b2 is before a2 or b2 is not followed by a char but work on given sample, so +1

Comment: @NeronLeVelu updated my answer since it was way to wide and will not work for `a2 c2`that should be deleted. `awk` is the east way to go.

Comment: Guys, `sed` is required

Comment: @OlegG I do know, but it does not hurt any body posting other solution.  `sed` may not always be the best tool, and if you have `sed` there are big possibility that you also have  `awk`.  You do not have `awk`?

Comment: @Jotne I don't have a problem to solve this in `awk`. I want to use `sed`'s -i option to avoid one line of code.

Comment: `sed -i 'code' file` does more or less the same as this `awk 'some code' file > tmp & mv tmp file` and this on one line too.  But I agree that there may be situation there `sed` is better than `awk`.

Comment: And, I'm sure you will agree, `sed -i 'code' file` is much more elegant than `awk 'some code' file > tmp & mv tmp file` (plus extra `rm -f tmp`). Why have we to write a code which does not delight our eyes then? :)

Comment: I do agree, but for complex solution `awk` is far superior. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n --posix -e '/a2/ !{
   p
   b
   }
/b2/ !p'
```

(adapted based on remark of Jotne + correction `b` instead of `t`)
print if not containing a2 then go to next line, if containt, print if not containing b2

or smaller

```
sed -n '/a2/ {/b2/ b
   }
p'
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, I do get this error `-bash: !{p: event not found`